# Glade can't find gui.glade

Tags: c#, mono

I'm using in my code:

```
Glade.XML gxml = new Glade.XML (null, "gui.glade", "PublicanCreators", null);
```

The gui.glade file is placed in the same [directory](https://github.com/saigkill/PublicanCreators/tree/master/PublicanCreators) as the Program.cs (which runs the code).

The compiling process has suceeded. But while running the exe i'm getting:

> Stacktrace:
>
> at  <0xffffffff>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   Glade.XML.gtksharp_glade_xml_get_filename (intptr)    at Glade.XML.get_Filename ()    at
>   (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_object__this__
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)    at 
>   <0xffffffff>   at Glade.XML..ctor
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly,string,string,string)    at PublicanCreators.GladeApp..ctor (string[]) [0x00018] in
>   /home/sascha/RiderProjects/PublicanCreators/PublicanCreators/Program.cs:40
>   at PublicanCreators.GladeApp.Main (string[]) [0x00002] in
>   /home/sascha/RiderProjects/PublicanCreators/PublicanCreators/Program.cs:34
>   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need gui.glade in the bin folder, not the source folder. Make sure it is included in your project file and is copied on compile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution is to change the code to:

```
Glade.XML gxml = new Glade.XML ("gui.glade", "PublicanCreators", null);
```

There it finds the file.